# How to filter a Table based on appartenance to a list

Tags: .net, filter, rethinkdb, reql

I am trying to filter a table , the predicate being the appartenance to a list in **Code**.
Can this be done from code and without needing the list to be added in a `RethinkDB` table?

```
var list=new List<int>{1,2,3};
var filter=r.Db("someDb").Table("SomeTable").Filter(x=>list.Contains(x("field")));
```

As you can see i have the list in `c#` but i cannot somehow put it as a predicate in `Reql` syntax.Is there anyway to do this?

Or can i somehow create an expression using a `for` like
    var basicExpression;

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
  basicExpression.Or(x("something").Eq(item));
}
```

And at the end make one big expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the javascript driver it is supposed to be like this:

```
r.db("someDb").table('SomeTable').filter(function (x) {
    return r.expr(['1', '2', '3']).contains(x('field'))
})
```

However, in the .net driver i am not sure, maybe:

```
var filter = r.Db("someDb").Table("SomeTable")
        .Filter(x => R.Expr(new[]{'1','2','3'}).Contains(x("field")));
```